# Beta regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, beta-function

Consider some positive random variables $X^1, X^2$ and $Y\sim Beta(p; 1)$ where $p=\beta_1X^1 + \beta_2X^2$. We have a random sample $\{X^1_i, X^2_i, Y_i\}$. Now, estimating $\beta_1, \beta_2$ is not hard, e.g. using GLM.

Now let's say that we do not observe $X^2$. Is it still possible to consistently estimate $\beta_1$ (i.e. using only a statistic consisting of $\{X^1_i, Y_i\}$)? If not, is there some assumption (normality etc.) for $X^i$ under which we can consistently estimate $\beta_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** I realized a problem with my previous post, here's an update with a general philosophy of "marginalizing" out unwanted covariates.

**Introduction**

Suppose we have a mean model
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y|X^1, X^2] &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2 X^2 \tag{$\heartsuit$}\\ 
\mathbb{E}[Y|X^1, X^2] &= e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2 X^2} \tag{$\diamondsuit$}
\end{align*}
Assuming $X^1 \perp \!\!\! \perp X^2$, we have from $(\heartsuit)$ the marginal model
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y|X^1] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X^1, X^2]] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2\mathbb{E}[X^2|X^1] = \beta_0^* + \beta_1^* X^1
\end{align*}
with $(\beta_0^*, \beta_1^*) = (\beta_0 + \beta_2\mathbb{E}[X^2|X^1], \beta_1)$ or from $(\diamondsuit)$ the marginal model
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y|X^1] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X^1, X^2]] = e^{\beta_0^* + \beta_1^* X^1}
\end{align*}
where $(\beta_0^*, \beta_1^*) = (\beta_0 + \log \mathbb{E}[e^{\beta_2 X^2}|X_1], \beta_1)$. In both these cases, where $Y$ is assumed to follow a linear or log-linear model with respect to covariates $X^1, X^2$, we have that the marginal coefficient $\beta_1^*$ is numerically equal to the full conditional model coefficient $\beta_1$.

**Consistently estimating a parameter**
[Generalized estimating equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation) set up equations of the form
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \mathbf{D}_k^\intercal \mathbf{V}_k^{-1}(\mathbf{Y}_k - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k) = \mathbf{0}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{Y}_k$ is a vector of observations which are believed with be correlated within itself, but $\mathbf{Y}_k \perp \!\!\! \perp \mathbf{Y}_{k'}$ (vectors are independent of each other). Without diving too deep into the theory of GEEs, the relevance here is that, as long as a mean model is correctly specified, fitting a GEE will always return consistent estimates of the desired coefficients. And a GLM is a special case of a GEE! What this implies, for example, if we have a model with
\begin{align*}
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1_i + \beta_2 X^2_i + \epsilon_i, \qquad \epsilon \sim F
\end{align*}
for any distribution $F$ with mean 0 and finite second moments (say, $\epsilon_i \sim \text{Exponential}(\frac{1}{2021}) - 2021$), fitting as if these errors were normal would still yield consistent estimates of $(\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2)$! Of course, the standard errors for these estimators would be incorrect and would need to be adjusted with [sandwich estimators](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ecensus/mlesan.pdf), but the consistency is not affected.

**Application to current problem**
The mean of $\text{Beta}(p, 1)$ is $\frac{p}{p+1}$, which is not a tractable form to perform the marginalization trick because of the "non-separability" of $X^2$ from $X^1$. My idea was to search for a transformation to make it more tractability, and once close transformation is setting $\widetilde{Y}_i = -\log(Y_i)$, which provides the mean model
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{Y}_i|X^1, X^2] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2 X^2}
\end{align*}
This still isn't quite there, but now if you're willing to accept the functional form
\begin{align*}
p = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2 X^2}
\end{align*}
(which somewhat makes more sence, since this guarantees $p > 0$ as needed in the beta distribution), we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{Y}_i|X^1, X^2] = e^{-\beta_0 - \beta_1 X^1 - \beta_2 X^2}
\end{align*}
and therefore the marginalization trick reveals
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{Y}_i|X^1] = e^{\beta_0^* + \beta_1^* X^1 }
\end{align*}
where $(\beta_0^*, \beta_1^*) = (-\beta_0 +\log \mathbb{E}[e^{-\beta_2 X^2}|X^1], -\beta_1)$. Essentially, we're treating the $X^2$ like errors in a normal regression model, but noting that they may not be mean 0 and therefore would bias the intercept. That's not a problem, since we are interested in $\beta_1$!

**Final procedure**

1. Transform $\widetilde{Y} = -\log(Y)$
2. Regress $\widetilde{Y}$ on $X^1$ with log link with any distribution you want (exponential, normal). The resulting coefficient is consistent for $-\beta_1$.

Comment: This is a very good answer, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal distribution would work as well"? I am very interested what you mean by this. Is there some similar transformation where we would get something like $\widetilde{Y}\sim N(p,1)$?

Comment: wait, isnt $$\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{Y}|X^1, X^2] = \frac{1}{ \beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2 X^2}$$?

Comment: I also had a small doubt. Once you derive that $E[\tilde{Y}|X_1]$ is linear in $X_1$, how would you proceed ? Still to make a formal regression you need some hypothesis on the residuals right ? So in theory you would need to know the distribution of $\tilde{Y}|X_1$ . The latter would also depend probably on the parameters $\beta_0, \beta_1$ that you want to find or not ?

Comment: ( I also have the same doubt of @Albert Paradek, now that I read his comment, but I am curious to know also how you would proceed if the expectation were linear )

Comment: Hey AlbertParadek and @Thomas, sorry for my sloppy answer before. I've updated with much more info, hope this helps

Comment: Interesting. But so I understand well that even if in a GLM we are modelling the errors with a wrong distribution, we are always consistent? ( i.e  in the limit of N large the result will always be correct? )

Comment: I would also clarify in your answer in the summary of the procedure that you changed the relation between X and p to a more reasonable one as far as I understood...

Comment: By the way, do you have any suggestion for the numerical approach in my answer?

Comment: I really like this, thanks @TomChen for your answer and time. Last thing that bothers me: 

You assumed that we parametrize $p=e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2}$. That's  
reasonable from the info you had. But actually what I am dealing with is that $p\in [0,1]$ (this holds from its interpretation). First thing I did was super simple- what if we put a linear link and don't care about the interpretation. But, maybe I am looking for some link like logit. Do you have some idea how to proceed in that case? I can put it as a new question and give you like 200 points if you solve that :D

Comment: Hi @Thomas, let me answer each of your questions accordingly:
*Modeling with wrong distributions in a GLM: As long as the mean model is correct, than yes, we get consistent estimates (but with wrong standard errors). For example, suppose $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X})$ and $Y \sim \text{Exp}(e^{-\beta_0 - \beta_1 X})$, which both has $E[Y|X] = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}$. If the Poisson model were the true model, but I model with the exponential, I'd still get consistent estimates for $\beta_0, \beta_1$.

Comment: @AlbertParadek By luck, a logit link extends naturally. With $\text{logit}(p) = \log(\frac{p}{1-p})$, the inverse link is $\text{expit}(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ and we have $p = \text{expit}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X^1 + \beta_2 X^2)$. This means that $\mathbb{E}[\widetilde{Y}|X^1, X^2] = \frac{1}{p} = 1 + e^{-\beta_0 - \beta_1 X^1 - \beta_2 X^2}$ and once again $X^1, X^2$ are separable. We just need to define outcomes $Y^\dagger = \widetilde{Y} - 1$ and the previous procedure would return consistent estimates for $-\beta_1$.

Comment: Hi @TomChen, thanks again. But unfortunately, it is still only a solution for "special cases". I am working with a few models, not sure which one to use and it would be really helpful to have also the classical linear case AND a case with some link between [-1,1] (i.e. modified expit such as $p=\frac{-1+e^{q}}{1+e^{q}}, q=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2  $ or something similar (we deal with covariance btw).) But this solution does not work for these cases. I opened a new question with this specifically, if you are interested to help a bit more :)

Comment: hups, i meant [1,2] not [-1,1] of course not negative. the question is here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351729/615430

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one can go numerical. In the presence of latent variables we have to maximize the marginal likelyhood, that here reads:

$log L=\sum_i log (\int dx^2_i p(x^1_1)p(x^2_i)y^{(\beta_1x_i^1+\beta_2x^2_i)}(\beta_1x_i^1+\beta_2x^2_i)$ [1]

One could try the EM algorithm and see if it simplifies things (but the nasty additive term mixing the parameters is not simplifying things...).

An other approach is upgrading $x^2_i$,$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ all to r.v. with a prior distribution and sample from the posterior or take a $MAP$ for all of them.

This can be done using PyMC3:

https://docs.pymc.io/en/v3/

https://discourse.pymc.io/t/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-a-bayesian-model/967

I would try to modify the code from here ( the first linear regression example ) in two ways:

https://docs.pymc.io/en/v3/pymc-examples/examples/getting_started.html

1. The distribution of $Y$ should follow your beta distribution ;
2. Upgrade $X_2$ to be a random variable with a prior distribution, rather than a fixed one ;

Having done this, you should be able to obtain MAP estimates for all variables and samples from the posterior. Each $x^i_2$ will be than treated as a parameter of the model so you would be sampling a space of dimensions of the number of samples that you have, therefore I am not sure how much this approach would be stable.

Comment: This approach is cool in theory, but ultimately because the "parameter dimension" equals your "sample size dimension", you are left with an identifiability problem. Adding a prior helps stabilize it, but the resulting estimates won't be consistent because we constantly have our sample size dominated by the number of parameters :(.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot for the feedback!

Comment: But now that I am thinking each time we have a latent variable per sample (e.g. gaussian mixtures) we have one parameter per sample, but this does not prevent us from applying these methods. What is different here?

Comment: Sorry Thomas that I didn't commented your solution, i must say its a bit too advanced for me to understand, a few expressions that have never encountered yet. I tried to look into them a bit but it's quite hard. I am sure that its an interesting solution though, thanks.

Comment: The other solution is much better :)